# Openswan Site-to-site VPN -- cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, ipsec, tunnel

I am setting up a ISPEC tunnel between a Linux System running Openswan and a Cisco ASA 5505. The strange thing is, the tunnel comes up I believe (based on the screenshots below), but I can't get traffic to traverse. I am wondering if it is an issue with the LAN being a Looopback interface on the Openswan system.

In summary ASA side(2.2.2.2) has LAN 192.168.0.0/24 and Openswan side(1.1.1.1) has LAN 172.16.255.1/32 which is a loopback interface on the Openwan system.

I am getting the following error and am fairly confident it has something to do with this line:

**`"L2L-IPSEC" #1: cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for 172.16.255.1/32===1.1.1.1<1.1.1.1>[+S=C]:1/0...2.2.2.2<2.2.2.2>[+S=C]:1/0===192.168.0.0/24`**

**Openswan output**

```
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: initiating Main Mode
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: received Vendor ID payload [RFC 3947] method set to=109
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: ignoring Vendor ID payload [Cisco IKE Fragmentation]
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: enabling possible NAT-traversal with method 4
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I1 to state STATE_MAIN_I2
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Cisco-Unity]
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: ignoring unknown Vendor ID payload [4fbc775ddcc5a56a715d9fb1a2c92d6a]
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: ignoring Vendor ID payload [Cisco VPN 3000 Series]
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using RFC 3947 (NAT-Traversal): no NAT detected
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I2 to state STATE_MAIN_I3
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
| protocol/port in Phase 1 ID Payload is 17/0. accepted with port_floating NAT-T
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: Main mode peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '68.99.157.15'
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I3 to state STATE_MAIN_I4
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: STATE_MAIN_I4: ISAKMP SA established {auth=OAKLEY_PRESHARED_KEY cipher=oakley_3des_cbc_192 prf=oakley_md5 group=modp1024}
"L2L-IPSEC" #2: initiating Quick Mode PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK {using isakmp#1 msgid:58792b0d proposal=AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160 pfsgroup=no-pfs}
"L2L-IPSEC" #2: ignoring informational payload, type IPSEC_RESPONDER_LIFETIME msgid=58792b0d
"L2L-IPSEC" #2: transition from state STATE_QUICK_I1 to state STATE_QUICK_I2
"L2L-IPSEC" #2: STATE_QUICK_I2: sent QI2, IPsec SA established tunnel mode {ESP=>0x6b58a97a <0x359aa18e xfrm=AES_256-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=none DPD=none}
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: the peer proposed: 172.16.255.1/32:0/0 -> 192.168.0.0/24:0/0
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for 172.16.255.1/32===1.1.1.1<1.1.1.1>[+S=C]:1/0...2.2.2.2<2.2.2.2>[+S=C]:1/0===192.168.0.0/24
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: sending encrypted notification INVALID_ID_INFORMATION to 2.2.2.2:500
```

**Cisco output:**

```
Apr 08 2014 09:02:25: %ASA-3-713902: Group = 1.1.1.1, IP = 1.1.1.1, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0xcc6e8cf8, mess id 0xd6971887)!
Apr 08 2014 09:02:25: %ASA-3-713902: Group = 1.1.1.1, IP = 1.1.1.1, Removing peer from correlator table failed, no match!
Apr 08 2014 09:02:25: %ASA-3-752015: Tunnel Manager has failed to establish an L2L SA.  All configured IKE versions failed to establish the tunnel. Map Tag= outside-cmap.  Map Sequence Number = 40.

asa# show crypto ikev1 sa

IKEv1 SAs:

   Active SA: 1
    Rekey SA: 0 (A tunnel will report 1 Active and 1 Rekey SA during rekey)
Total IKE SA: 1

1   IKE Peer: 1.1.1.1
    Type    : L2L             Role    : initiator
    Rekey   : no              State   : MM_ACTIVE

asa# show crypto ipsec sa
interface: outside
    Crypto map tag: outside-cmap, seq num: 40, local addr: 2.2.2.2

      access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.255.1
      local ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
      remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (172.16.255.1/255.255.255.255/0/0)
      current_peer: 1.1.1.1

      #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
      #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
      #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
      #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts comp failed: 0, #pkts decomp failed: 0
      #pre-frag successes: 0, #pre-frag failures: 0, #fragments created: 0
      #PMTUs sent: 0, #PMTUs rcvd: 0, #decapsulated frgs needing reassembly: 0
      #TFC rcvd: 0, #TFC sent: 0
      #Valid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0, #Invalid ICMP Errors rcvd: 0
      #send errors: 0, #recv errors: 0

      local crypto endpt.: 2.2.2.2/0, remote crypto endpt.: 1.1.1.1/0
      path mtu 1500, ipsec overhead 74(44), media mtu 1500
      PMTU time remaining (sec): 0, DF policy: copy-df
      ICMP error validation: disabled, TFC packets: disabled
      current outbound spi: 529934CE
      current inbound spi : CFD6928B

    inbound esp sas:
      spi: 0xCFD6928B (3486945931)
         transform: esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac no compression
         in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, IKEv1, }
         slot: 0, conn_id: 917504, crypto-map: outside-cmap
         sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4374000/28735)
         IV size: 16 bytes
         replay detection support: Y
         Anti replay bitmap:
          0x00000000 0x00000001
    outbound esp sas:
      spi: 0x529934CE (1385772238)
         transform: esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac no compression
         in use settings ={L2L, Tunnel, IKEv1, }
         slot: 0, conn_id: 917504, crypto-map: outside-cmap
         sa timing: remaining key lifetime (kB/sec): (4374000/28735)
         IV size: 16 bytes
         replay detection support: Y
         Anti replay bitmap:
          0x00000000 0x00000001
```

**Openswan /etc/network/interfaces:**

```
 auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

 auto lo:1
  iface lo:1 inet static
    address 172.16.255.1
    netmask 255.255.255.255

 auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
   address 1.1.1.1
   gateway 1.1.1.254
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

**Openswan Config:**

```
config setup
        listen=1.1.1.1
        dumpdir=/var/run/pluto
        nat_traversal=yes #pretty sure this isn't needed
        virtual_private=%v4:192.168.0.0/24
        oe=off
        protostack=netkey

conn L2L-IPSEC
        authby=secret #use shared secret
        auto=start #automatically start if detected
        type=tunnel #tunnel mode/not transport

        ###THIS SIDE###
        left=1.1.1.1
        leftsubnet=172.16.255.1/32
        leftsourceip=172.16.255.1

        ###PEER SIDE###
        right=2.2.2.2
        rightsubnet=192.168.0.0/24

        #phase 1 encryption-integrity-diffhellman
        keyexchange=ike
        ike=3des-md5-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024
        ikelifetime=86400s

        #phase 2 encryption-pfsgroup
        phase2=esp #esp for encryption | ah for authentication only
        phase2alg=aes256-sha1;modp1024
        pfs=no
```

**Cisco ASA Config:**

```
crypto ipsec ikev1 transform-set vps1TS esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac

crypto map outside-cmap 40 match address VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1
crypto map outside-cmap 40 set peer 1.1.1.1
crypto map outside-cmap 40 set ikev1 transform-set vps1TS
crypto map outside-cmap interface outside

crypto ikev1 policy 1
 authentication pre-share
 encryption 3des
 hash md5
 group 2
 lifetime 86400
crypto ikev1 policy 2
 authentication pre-share
 encryption aes-256
 hash sha
 group 2
 lifetime 86400

 access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1; 2 elements; name hash: 0xa6c3fa81
access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 line 1 extended permit icmp object inside-network object vps1-network (hitcnt=3183) 0xed457442
  access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 line 1 extended permit icmp 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.255.1 (hitcnt=3183) 0xed457442
access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 line 2 extended permit ip object inside-network object vps1-network (hitcnt=88) 0xbddc26cf
  access-list VPN-TRAFFIC-VPS1 line 2 extended permit ip 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0 host 172.16.255.1 (hitcnt=88) 0xbddc26cf


object network inside-network
 subnet 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0

object network vps1-network
 subnet 172.16.255.1 255.255.255.255

nat (inside,outside) source static inside-network inside-network destination static vps1-network vps1-network
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It does indeed seem that the problem is on your Openswan server.  These lines from the output of your ASA indicates the Firewall has never received any packets through the VPN:

```
  #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
  #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
```

(from the command "show ipsec sa")

I'm sorry, I don't know Openswan very well (or at all), so I'm unable to provide any suggestions to that regards.  :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems you added more debug output since I last viewed this.  I don't know if this is still an issue, but if so, the problem is identified here:

```
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: the peer proposed: 172.16.255.1/32:0/0 -> 192.168.0.0/24:0/0
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: cannot respond to IPsec SA request because no connection is known for 172.16.255.1/32===1.1.1.1<1.1.1.1>[+S=C]:1/0...2.2.2.2<2.2.2.2>[+S=C]:1/0===192.168.0.0/24
"L2L-IPSEC" #1: sending encrypted notification INVALID_ID_INFORMATION to 2.2.2.2:500
```

This is from your Opanswan output.  This is telling you that you have a mismatch in the "Encryption Domain" (or "Interesting Traffic", or other such terminology) of the configuration.  One side is proposing one set of networks, and the other side is expecting another set of networks.

It could also be an issue in the "identity" portion of both peers.  I am not sure how to check it in Openswan (or rather, how to check the configuration for the "identity" portion), but on the ASA you'll want to look for a line that looks like "crypto isakmp identity" or potentially "crypto ikev1 identity" if you are running 8.4+.

Comment: users flagging: Yes, this isn't really an answer, it should be a comment under the original Q... but I cannot convert it directly into a comment because it is too long and gets truncated horribly.